# losing reference of trace/span while calling opentelemetry in rust from C (FFI)

Tags: c, rust, ffi, open-telemetry

I am trying to call opentelemetry libraries from my C code using Rust FFI. However, I am having hard time to keep the trace/span alive after the FFI call, since I need the reference of span to end it in right time, and trace to create nested spans.

I tried using global variable in rust, but after the FFI call, I lose the trace as it creates a new trace with different id. I cannot pass it as argument since the type of trace and span are not c compatible.
Can anyone suggest a way where I can keep the reference of span & trace in rust even after FFI call from C.

Comment: FWIW, I'm trying to wrap my head around the same problem in C++ with the official C++ implementation (opentelemetry-cpp).